# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime`

Tags: java, jackson

In Json return the field date time:

```
"date": "2023-09-22 01:07:50.062477"
```

In class Json:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
public LocalDateTime date;
```

Return error:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2023-09-22 02:11:13.855618')

How to solve?

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
public LocalDateTime date;
```

Comment: The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 standard formats when parsing/generating text. That means using a `T` in the middle rather than the SPACE seen in your text: `2023-09-22T02:11:13.855618`.  I guess you either need to correct your inputs to comply with ISO 8601 or you need to configure Jackson with a formatter to parse your particular inputs.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1):

you are getting that error since Json is trying to deserialize the date sting into instance of `LocalDateTime`  but it not being able to do that due no constructor or such method on that class.

You can get to solution by creating a custom deserializer class by extending `JsonDeserializer` and override the deserializer method and return to required by Parsing.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

public class CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        String dateStr = jsonParser.getValueAsString();
        return LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, formatter);
    }
}
```

Then annotate the field with custom deserializer instead.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
public LocalDateTime date;
```

I am sure that you have this dependency.

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
```

Hope this works for you. I did have get some shortcut just before 3-4 months. Sorry I forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

Am no sure how you interact from front end, passing json data from the front end or when you call the end point just put this to the @PathVariable or @RequestParam like this in controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/v{version}", produces = "application/json")
ResponseEntity<List<Test>> findByDate(@RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime date)}
```

Use this standard ISO method.